# UITextView - Setting attributes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, attributes, uitextview

I have a UITextView and a bar with three buttons which toggle bold, italic and underline.
I've set the TextView's text to attributed and it's "Allow Editing Attributes" option to YES.
Although the code for editing a selected text is working (here's an example):

```
       UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];



    //edit selection

    NSRange selectedRange = _noteTextView.selectedRange;


    [[_noteTextView textStorage] beginEditing];

    [[_noteTextView textStorage] addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:selectedRange];

    [[_noteTextView textStorage] addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:selectedRange];

    [[_noteTextView textStorage] endEditing];



    [[_noteTextView textStorage] setAttributes:dict range:selectedRange];
```

I am having problems with setting the attributes at my textview's indicator.
`[[_noteTextView textStorage] addAttribute:]` is not working or I might have a problem with the range.
Any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ... and we don't know what you mean when you just vaguely state that your code "is not working".  How is it not working?  What is it doing?  And how does that compare to what it is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Well , what I ask the TableView to "addAttribute" at the indicator (without selecting anything), and when I start typing, the attributes haven't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to set the range [textView rangeForUserParagraphAttributeChange];

It will set the attributes for the whole paragraph not just the selected range.

EDIT:
If there is text beyond the caret position you may have to extend the range by one character in order to ensure that subsequent characters that are typed in will fall within the range the attributes were applied to.

Applying attributes to a range does just that, it applies them to the range not to any text typed in beyond the range. If the length of the range is ZERO (i.e. nothing selected) then my guess is your attributes get applied to nothing.